# How to change Data Type from Object to just date format?

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe, jupyter

For one of the columns of my DataFrame, I have a date which is in the format: 2019-01-31 however the data type of this column is Object. I am not very used to python as I am a beginner so was hoping someone could help me figure out how to change the data type so that this column can be recognized as a date?
Not sure if this has already been asked before because I was unable to find it on here.

Comment: Check with [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html). If that doesn't work let us know the specific issue you encounter.

Comment: I get an error saying: Series' object has no attribute 'pd'

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this has been answered elsewhere. Using pandas:

```
df['Column']= pd.to_datetime(df['Column'], errors='coerce')
```

If errors = ‘coerce’, then invalid parsing will be set as NaN